# How to show static data within a job step on Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Google Dataflow with a custom pipeline written in python with Apache Beam to perform some transformation on my data.

My pipeline use the ReadFromBigQuery transform, and I noticed that if I expand the the pipeline step in the job graph, by clicking on some of the inner steps I can see some static information. For example:
[step details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW41N.jpg)

Here if I click on the inner ParDo step (ReadFromBigQuery/Read/SDFBoundedSourceReader/ParDo), on the right panel I can see some detail about my read operation, for example the method, query used etc. However they are not visible by clicking the outer main PTransform ReadFromBigQuery.

I would like to change that, and also show other static information so others can see and understand what that pipeline step is doing without having to break down the main step.

By looking at the documentation and at the source code of ReadFromBigQuery, to my understanding the [display_data()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.18.0/apache_beam.transforms.display.html#apache_beam.transforms.display.HasDisplayData.display_data) method is used to accomplish this, but I don't understand how to use it.

I tried to wrap the ReadFromBigQuery in another class and redefine display_data(), something like this:

```
class ReadFromQuery(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query=query
    def expand(self,pcol):
        return pcol | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(...)
    def display_data(self):
        return {'query':self.query}
```

But it's not working. Am I missing something?

EDIT: display_data() seems to not work on PTransform objects. I tried it on custom DoFn objects and I can see my data on the Dataflow GUI.

Comment: return {f'query: {self.query}'}

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? display_data() expects a dict as the return type. It gives me an error if I return a set object with that string